# Having both Visual Assist X 10.6 and Resharper How to make VAX turn off on C# projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-assist

Having VAX and RS installed how to make VAX turn off on C# projects (because Resharper and default VS2012 hightlightning are more acceptable for me)?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

http://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W372

Add .cs to the "Extensions to Ignore" under Projects and Files.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot choose to disable language-specific but disable global. In the VS main window go to 
    `VAssistX -> Enable / Disable Visual Assist X`